# How to execute a .bat or exe file from CodedUI script using Process.Start()?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new to Coded UI. I have written a simple code to execute a .bat file from a CodedUITestMethod1() as below:

```js
  thisProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  thisProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  thisProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\BVTBatch\PlayBack.bat";
  thisProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  thisProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            
  thisProcess.Start();
  thisProcess.WaitForExit();
  strException = thisProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Problem statement: When I debug the script, it gets executed but the batch file does not run. I tried executing iexplorer.exe, and observed same issue. The script gets executed with pass, but IE browser does not start.

However if I execute the same code from other console application or Unit Test project method, it gets executed successfully.

Can someone suggest what is the reason behind this? and how can we fix this in CodedUI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you determining whether the process has started or not ? Do you have any logging in your .bat file ? You should check the return value of `.Start` to see whether it has really started the process or has it failed ?

Answer (score 0):

This would seem legit:

```
 thisProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ("C:\BVTBatch\PlayBack.bat");
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I checked but the path is correct and it still does not execute the .bat file after using this: ("C:\\BVTBatch\\PlayBack.bat");

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo ("C:\BVTBatch\PlayBack.bat");
p.Start();
```